# what is account_name in Google My Business API?

Tags: google-api, review, google-my-business-api

I want to display all customers review on my web page. For that, I refer [Get a review](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/review-data#get_a_review) in the documentation.

But I am confused about  account_name in the following request

```
https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/account_name/locations/location_name/reviews
```

What value should i use for account_name?

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code and describe any issues you are having.  As it is written it is hard to understand what your issue is.

Comment: My question is simple what is account_name in this api?

Comment: If that was your question why wasnt it the title of the question?

Answer (score 0):

- Account_name = the name of the account you want to get data for
- Location_name = the name of the location that you want to get reviews for

Use [accounts list](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts/list) to find a list of accounts the current user has access to.  Use [locations list](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations/list) with account to find a list of the locations for that account

As you can see by the documentation [accounts list](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts/list) returns a list of account objects.

**Accounts.list**

```
{
  "accounts": [
    {
      object(Account)
    }
  ],
  "nextPageToken": string
}
```

An [account resource](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts#Account) contains a list of account_name's for the user who is currently authenticated.

```
{
  "name": string,
  "accountName": string,
  "type": enum(AccountType),
  "role": enum(AccountRole),
  "state": {
    object(AccountState)
  },
  "profilePhotoUrl": string,
  "accountNumber": string,
  "permissionLevel": enum(PermissionLevel),
  "organizationInfo": {
    object(OrganizationInfo)
  }
}
```

**Access**

Remember you must fill out the form and request access to this api [here](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/prereqs#request-access)

**Authorization**

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

Means that your request must be authenticated before you can use this method.  YOu cant access private user data without the permission of the user who owns the data.  [Oauth](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/basic-setup#request-client-id)  I recommend you find the client library for your chosen language and look for information on how to authenticate using oauth2

Comment: Still, I have no an idea that where is my account name?

Comment: As mentioned in the last sentience.   Use account.list to get back a list of account names for the user who is currently authenticated.   Check my update see if that is not more clear.

Comment: I run this API "https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts" But it throws an error that's why I ask you again.

Comment: Check Authorization section of my answer..  You need to be authenticated using Oauth2 to use this api.  You cant just send the url supplying an access token (which you got from an oauth2 login) in the request as well.   (Authorization header bearer token)